# Which web part will display the current user?

Tags: user-profile, web-part

Do you know what web part I can use to display the picture of the current user?

Answer (score 1):

- An answer for Sharepoint 2007 is found here: [How to get current user display image in Sharepoint?](http://efreedom.com/Question/1-2242952/Get-Current-User-Display-Image-Sharepoint)
- Another tutorial on the blog of Tobias Zimmergreen: [SharePoint's hidden user-list - User Information List](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2008/06/25/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list.aspx):

For Sharepoint 2010 I'd do something lke Tobias Zimmergreen did. It is not OOTB, but very easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a single webpart that does that for you -but it is still possible. You need two things: 
(1) Current user filter- webpart 
(2) Image library with user photos in it.

- Add both webparts to your SharePoint site.
- Create a column in the image library called "username"
- Upload some user photos and fill out the column "username" with the account name (e.g. "domain\myaccount"). Make sure you include yourself, so that testing is easy.
- Now connect your current user filter- webpart with your image library, so that the filter webpart sends its data to the image library

Just tried it on my machine. The filtering works perfectly but you probably want to "tune" the site design a little.

Comment: Is the Current user filter - webpart a feature in SharePoint 2010 Enterprise edition? I don't see it in my Standard edition.